# Power Density parameter in Ultra Low Power (ULP) devices

Tags: power, digital-logic, low-power

I'm doing a bit of research on ULP processors.

In a few papers (e.g. ["Energy-Efficient Near-Threshold Parallel Computing: The PULPv2 Cluster"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8065010)) I found a figure of merit called "power density" and defined as Pdens = uW/MHz, so basically it is energy.

The thing is I don't understand what it means, I'm not sure when this would be useful either.

From my understanding:

A circuit consuming 10 W @ 25 MHz has a Pdens1 = 10/25 W/MHz = 0.4 W/MHz. If it was running @ 50 MHz but still consuming 10 W then it would be Pdens2 = 0.2 W/MHz.

To me, Pdens2 is better than Pdens1 since the goal is to minimize power consumption.

Any hints? Or good introductions books/article to ULP which better explains figure of merit like this and Energy Efficiency (MOPS/mw), for example.

Comment: The higher the frequency, the more the power dissipation will be. All else equal, a processor that consumes 10 W at 25 MHz will need 20 W at 50 MHz.

Comment: Fine, but when is this expression useful then?

Answer (score 1):

The higher the frequency, the more the power dissipation will be. All else equal, a processor that consumes 10 W at 25 MHz will need 20 W at 50 MHz*.

The power density (I'm not familiar with this name for it, but I'll assume you have it correct) is roughly constant for a given processor, so if you have a power density of 0.4 W/MHz, you can predict how much power it will consume for different clock speeds.

It helps you to compare the relative performance of different processors; if one processor you're considering using is rated to consume 10 W at 20 MHz, and another one consumes 20 W at 50 MHz, but you only need to clock the processor at 10 MHz, you'd have to do the math yourself to find which one would consume more power at that clock speed. But if instead they were rated at 0.5 W/MHz and 0.4 W/MHz, you can clearly see that no matter the clock speed, the second processor will consume less power than the first.

*note: It's not exactly linear, but it's a good approximation. At very low frequencies especially, though, don't expect the relation to hold. Actually, don't expect your processor to *work*; most processors have a minimum frequency below which they won't work.

Comment: That is what I did not know; linearity. To check my understanding: https://send.firefox.com/download/c1a939f84c3c6f0a/#_JC7vZdcXFv8LnMd-kS_zw

Answer (score 0):

> In a few papers I found a figure of merith called power density and defined as Pdens = uW/MHz, so basically it is energy.

"Power density" in this case is just energy required to do one cycle of computation.  If you multiplied by how much work per cycle the processor did, you would have computational efficiency.

> The thing is I don't understand what it means, I'm not sure when this would be useful either.

It is an easy to measure parameter that is roughly proportional to efficiency.  It isn't the same as efficiency itself, but measuring that would be hard since how much work per cycle a processor can do depends on the specific thing it is doing.  Having an easy to measure figure of merit is very useful.

> To me, Pdens2 is better than Pdens1 since the goal is to minimize power consumption. Any hints?

That is correct.  The processor that is more efficient is better according to this metric.

Answer (score 0):

This figure is used to compare power efficiency of different processors. The lower the number, the better is power efficiency.